# TcpListener blocks thread while listening for incoming messages from TcpClients

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcplistener

I created a new .NET Core worker service project. This service should also act as a TCP socket server and listen for incoming messages. So based on [the code sample from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netcore-3.1) this is what I'm basically doing

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
        tcpListener.Start();
        
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                NetworkStream tcpClientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                using StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(tcpClientStream);
                string messageText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        
                // ... do things with messageText ...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // ... error handling ...
        }

        await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

The `ExecuteAsync` method won't get called anymore because the code is stuck in the `while` loop in the `StartAsync` method. When I comment out the whole overriding `StartAsync` method everything works fine, the `ExecuteAsync` method gets called.

Is it possible to get rid of the blocking while loop and make use of event handlers or something like that?

Comment: `await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()` will block until there's a connection, so you most likely don't want to do it there. Probably move that to `ExecuteAsync` or a separate method called from `ExecuteAsync`?

Comment: This appears to be essentially [the same question you already posted and deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63550352/how-to-listen-for-incoming-tcp-messages-from-sockets-without-blocking-the-thread). **Do not repost questions**. If you are disappointed in the response received for a question you've posted, the correct way to deal with it is to **improve the original question**. Reposting the same question is against Stack Overflow community guidelines, and is counterproductive.

Answer (score 2):

A `BackgroundService`'s typical pattern it to simply override `ExecuteAsync` and wait for the `stoppingToken` to signal and then exit immediately.

Take a look at the source code for [BackgroundService](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs).

If you want to use a "start/stop" pattern, then implement `IHostedService`.

If you want to use `BackgroundService`, then it should be laid out as so:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
    tcpListener.Start();
    
    try
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(); // READ BELOW ABOUT THIS
            NetworkStream tcpClientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            using StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(tcpClientStream);
            string messageText = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    
            // ... do things with messageText ...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // ... error handling ...
    }
}
```

Now, the biggest problem here is that `AccpetTcpClientAsync` doesn't have cancellation capabilities. So, you may have to implement [something like this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/).

So then you could do:

```
var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().WithCancellation(stoppingToken);
```

And just swallow the `OperationCancelledExeption` that would be thrown in that case.

> Edited To Add

Another option is that you could skip the async/await versions all together and use the `Begin../End...` (`BeginAcceptTcpClient()`, in this case). I tend to go down that path a lot. It's very convenient to have an event fire when something connects. Keep in mind your `TcpListener` would need to be on the class scope at that point so it doesn't dispose.